# copy and symlink mysql to another disk partition

Tags: mysql, symlink, io

I'm using ubuntu 12.04 and have two disk partition named: */dev/sda* and */dev/sdb*.

my *home* partition and other programs are in */dev/sda*.
therefor any work like database benchmark on my mysql databases will do *IO Transactions* on */dev/sda*.

I'm going to do (or redirect) this IO *Transactions* on(to) */dev/sdb*.
my search results show that i should copy my myql folder to */dev/sdb* and then using *symlink* create a symbolic link from mysql to new mysql in */dev/sdb*.

first of all, does this solution is correct? if so, how can i exactly do that? and what should i consider(such as using *cp* or *rsync* command for copy files.)?

[here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/symbolic-links.html) is symlink for mysql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the section [8.12.4 Using Symbolic Links](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/symbolic-links.html) is advising you that it is possible to make the database-directory (such as `/var/lib/mysql`) a symbolic link to another location with more space.  With Ubuntu, you can do that, or you could make `/dev/sdb` *mounted* on `/var/lib/mysql`.  A mountpoint may be (slightly) more efficient.

Either way, to migrate your database to the other filesystem, you would

- shutdown mysql (e.g., `mysqld`).
- use `rsync` for copying the files,
- for the moment, rename the old database directory (in case you made an error),
- make your symbolic link (or create a new directory as a mountpoint, mount the large filesystem there)
- start up mysql
- verify that it works
- remove the renamed/saved database directory

In either case, the *device* `/dev/sdb` has to be *mounted* on a directory.  This is done in `/etc/fstab`, and is manipulated using the `mount` and `umount` commands.

Further reading:

- [rsync](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/rsync1.html)
- [Commonly Used rsync Arguments](http://www.evbackup.com/support-commonly-used-rsync-arguments/)
- [fstab](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/fstab.5.html)
- [mount](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html) / [umount](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/umount.8.html)
- [how to move a mysql database to another mount point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743245/how-to-move-a-mysql-database-to-another-mount-point)
- [MySQL data on secondary hard disk](http://dev-random.net/mysql-data-on-secondary-hard-disk/)

Comment: fi my benchmark creates new database and tables does new database and tables creates on */dev/sdb*?

Comment: Once you've migrated everything, the new disk acts just like the old disk -- for that directory.